# Google places set focus on search bar?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using the places SDK for Android in my app with the Autocomplete widget in OVERLAY mode. I am able to search and retrieve addresses etc the issue I am having is that when the widget loads the search bar I don't want to the user to have to click into the search bar that is displayed in order to type the search details.

How do I make the cursor appear in the search bar and the keyboard open so the user can just start typing?

```
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
            Objects.requireNonNull(autocompleteFragment).setHint("Search Postcode");

    AutocompleteFilter filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setCountry("GB")
            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(filter);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
           editTextaddr.setText(place.getAddress());
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            editTextaddr.setText(status.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having been in contact with googles support team this has been raised as a bug when using the Places SDK for Android with Android API 28

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124740771